# Vim how can I move text into a set of parentheses?

Tags: vim

In Vim, this has been happening to me and I'm wondering the best way to handle it. Example:

`something(|)something, else` *// pipe is the cursor location*

I'd like to end up with this:

`something(something, else)`

I'd also like to be able to do this:

`something(something) else` _// in case I only want the first word

Comment: I would simply `dl` to delete the next letter, hit `$` to move to the end of the line, and hit `p` to paste the deleted `)`. I'm not sure what else you're after.

Comment: you can use vim-surround plugin. Visually select the required text followed by S(

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in insert mode:

```
" first example
<Del><S-Right><S-Right><S-Right>)
```

and:

```
" second example
<Del><S-Right><Del>)
```

Assuming you are in normal mode, with the cursor on the closing parenthesis:

```
" first example
x$p
```

and:

```
" second example
xeplx
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the pair of paranthesis has no space in between so that it looks like `()word, another-word etc etc`. Then

```
d EEp
```

changes it into `(word, another-word) etc etc`.

The `d` initiates a delete. The following space tells vim how much you want to delete: one character (this is the `)`). An `E` jumps over a word. So, the double `EE` jumps over two words. With the final `p` you insert (paste) what you have deleted (that is the `)`).